# Required properties are undefined

Tags: typescript

I was surprised to find out that TypeScript class properties can disappear from the transpiled output if they are never assigned a value.

This TypeScript class...

```
class Foo {
    value: any;
}
```

Becomes..

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

The `Foo.value` property is not declared as an optional property so I would expect the constructor to create that property, regardless of whether it has been assigned a value.

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'value', {});
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

How do I get that behavior?

Comment: Could it be just kind of an optimization? There is no sense in creating any code for properties that are never assigned, hence, always undefined.

Comment: So is there no testable difference between a property whose value is set to `undefined` and the complete absence of a property?

Comment: I believe `hasOwnProperty` will behave differently @StevenLiekens

Comment: But keep in mind that TS works assuming a fully TS system.

Comment: Typescript does type checking only, it does not generate any javascript code which is not present in the typescript source code. Well it does, sort of, it generates code to support es6 features when they are used and the target language is es5, BUT declaring properties in a class body is not  a es6 feature.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to guarantee this property is transpiled is to assign it a value... an explicit null should work for you.

```
class Foo {
    value: any = null;
}
```

Constructor properties are also always output:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public value: any) { }
}
```

Or if you desperately want it done with `Object.defineProperty`...

```
class Foo {
    private _foo: string;

    get foo() { return this._foo; }
    set foo(value: string) { this._foo = value;}
}
```

Comment: This will translate to `this.value = value`, not `Object.defineProperty(...)`.

Comment: Additional example added.